# foreach where loop using query builder results in controller laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have the **Hostel** and **Block** models as follows:

```
 class Hostel extends Model
      {
       //use Sortable;
       public function block()
       {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Block');
       }
    }

class Block extends Model
{
    // use Sortable;
     public function hostel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hostel');
    }
}
```

I have the variables `$gender` and `$capacity` which are passed from the view through the URL. In my **`HostelContoller.php`** i am trying to get all `blocks` of the hostels with column `gender = $gender` and these `blocks` should be having column `capacity = $capacity`. This is what i have done in `HostelContoller.php`

```
public function hostels($gender, $capacity)
    {  
        $hostels = Hostel::where('gender', $gender)->get();
        foreach($hostels as $hostel) { 
            $blocks = Block::where('capacity', $capacity)
                            ->where('hostel_id', $hostel->id)
                            ->get();


        }

        # Return the view
        return view('student/booking', ['blocks' => $blocks]);
    }
```

In `booking.php` I have this :

```
@foreach($blocks as $block)
          <tr>

            <td>  {{ $block->hostel->name }}</td>
            <td>  {{ $block ->name}}</td>
```

This is only displaying 1 record out of 6 records and i don't know where I am missing it. Please help!!!

Comment: What's inside `$hostel->id`?

Comment: It is the `ids` of the hostels from the hostels table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rewrite $blocks variable everytime of loop. You should add block to $blocks like this:

```
public function hostels($gender, $capacity)
            {  
                $hostels = Hostel::where('gender', $gender)->get();
                $blocks = array();
                foreach($hostels as $hostel) { 
                    $blocks[] = Block::where('capacity', $capacity)
                                    ->where('hostel_id', $hostel->id)
                                    ->get();
                }

                # Return the view
                return view('student/booking', ['blocks' => $blocks]);
            }
```